# Is there a lightweight way to stream HLS Video in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I am currently running a React Typescript application that streams HLS video with the .m3u8 file type. Initially we used the videojs library to handle this, but changed to React-Hls-Player to reduce the bundle size of our application. RHP is definitely smaller and does the job, but it is still very large due to using hls.js.

[This issue](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/1234) points to the min- and light-versions of hls.js, but I am unsure how I can implement these versions while using the RHP package. I am open to changing from RHP as well, if anyone has a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [media-chrome project?](https://github.com/muxinc/media-chrome) It's built with web components using many native APIs and is reporting in at 20.8kb minified + gzipped.

Full disclosure, I'm a community engineer at Mux, the company behind this project, but the repository is entirely OSS.